# TimerTask not applicable to arguments

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, timertask

My main program is as follows:

```
package priceCollector;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class App extends TimerTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date now = new Date();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        String s = df.format(now);

        String fileName = "/Users/Desktop/" + s + ".csv";

        URL link = null;
        try {
             link = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=III.L+ADM.L+AAL.L+ANTO.L+AHT.L+ABF.L+AZN.L+AV.L+BAB.L+BA.L+BARC.L+BDEV.L+BLT.L+BP.L+BATS.L+BLND.L+BTA.L+BNZL.L+BRBY.L+CPI.L+CCL.L+CNA.L+CCH.L+CPG.L+CRH.L+CRDA.L+DCC.L+DGE.L+DLG.L+DC.L+EZJ.L+EXPN.L+FRES.L+GKN.L+GSK.L+GLEN.L+HMSO.L+HL.L+HIK.L+HSBA.L+IMB.L+INF.L+IHG.L+IAG.L+ITRK.L+INTU.L+ITV.L+JMAT.L+KGF.L+LAND.L+LGEN.L+LLOY.L+LSE.L+MKS.L+MDC.L+MERL.L+MCRO.L+MNDI.L+MRW.L+NG.L+NXT.L+OML.L+PPB.L+PSON.L+PSN.L+POLY.L+PFG.L+PRU.L+RRS.L+RB.L+REL.L+RIO.L+RR.L+RBS.L+RDSA.L+RDSB.L+RMG.L+RSA.L+SGE.L+SBRY.L+SDR.L+SVT.L+SHP.L+SKY.L+SN.L+SMIN.L+SSE.L+STJ.L+STAN.L+SL.L+TW.L+TSCO.L+TPK.L+TUI.L+ULVR.L+UU.L+VOD.L+WTB.L+WOS.L+WPG.L+WPP.L&f=np");

             InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
             ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
             int n = 0;
             while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf))){
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
             }
             out.close();
             in.close();
             byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
             fos.write(response);
             fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("not available");
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when ran alone, however i am trying to set a regular schedule which will make it rund daily. My TimerTask program is:

```
package priceCollector;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimerTask {

    public void runTask(){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object

        // Start running the task on Thursday at 21:15:00, period is set to 1 day
        // if you want to run the task immediately, set the 2nd parameter to 0
        time.schedule(new App(), calendar.getTime(), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8));  
    }
}
```

the final line (schedule argument) give the following error:

> The method schedule(TimerTask, Date, long) in the type Timer is not
>   applicable for the arguments (App, Date, long)

not sure what this is. new to Java! thanks.

Comment: your problem is, that your try to call the method `schedule(...)` with a an object of type `App` instead of `TimerTask`. The error message basically says that the types you pass as a parameter do not match. Try `new TimerTask(...)` instead (can't help you with the arguments since I don't know the class...)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is the initial delay as shown in the API below:

```
//Example, If you want to configure the initial delay as 5 seconds
time.schedule(new App(), 5000, TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8));
```

> public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)

task - task to be scheduled.

delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.

period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.